# Как передать данные с одного js файла в другой?

Tags: javascript, vaadin

Я не так давно работаю с `javascript` и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Мне необходимо передать данные с одного js файла в другой. (Разделение на несколько файлов неизбежно, в силу того, что один js файл используется как `javascript connector` с `Java(Vaadin)`). В другом js файле находится логика с работой данными. Пробовал реализовывать паттерн "наблюдатель" в третьем файле, и использовать объекты его типа в обоих других файлах, но получаю ошибку, что  *`Observable не определен`*, при условии того, что в html файле первым загружаемым скриптом идет сам "наблюдатель", потом следующие два файла.

Вообще, что я хочу сделать: При изменении данных в `file1.js`, данные менялись в `file2.js`. Есть еще одна особенность: `file2.js` содержит только одну анонимную функцию и больше ничего, такое условие для js-java connector в VAADIN

Comment: А использование обычной глобальной переменной не помогает?. По идее если в одном файле прописать `var  my_global` то с этой переменной можно работать в любом файле.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте объект window - как хранилище для ваших переменных ( с учетом, что в вашей анонимной ф-ции есть доступ к window, мало ли что там в js-java connector )

**file1**

```
window.storage = {}; // для пространства имен, что бы много мусора в window не пихать
window.storage.globalVar = 100;
```

**file2**

```
(function () {
    /** анонимная ф-ция с вашим js-java connector */
    var localVar = window.storage.globalVar;
})();
```